# C - stackdump, strange output with multiple fork+redirect+exec

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, exec, io-redirection

I have a C program (let's call it "`progam1`") as well as 3 input files (say `"in1.txt", "in2.txt", in3.txt"`) and 3 initially empty output files (`"out1, "out2","out3"`) that represent operations on various polygons.

From `progam1::main`, I call fork 3 times, and within each child process, I use `dup2` to redirect standard input/output into one of the input/output files, and then call execve("helper",...), where `helper` is another C program that parses the input, does some calculations, and prints output.

The problem I can't seem to solve is whenever I call `execve(helper,...)` more than once, the first call works fine (input/output is as I'd expect), but then something goes wrong; I seem to either end up with a file `helper.exe.stackdump`, or the system continually prints the same data to an output file, or some other unexpected result.

As an experiment, I wrote another C program - `"simpleWrite.c"`, which simply copies the input to the output. I'm running all these programs using cygwin.

- If I pass `simpleWrite` to all 3 `execve` calls in `program1`,
  then everything works fine (all 3 redirected inputs are copied to the
  3 output files as expected).
- If I pass `simpleWrite` to one child (say the 3rd child) and run `./program1` from the terminal, then the system finishes and the 1st and 3rd child processes work as expected. The 2nd output is empty, and I end up with a file `"helper.exe.stackdump"` in my directory.
- If I only pass `helper` to all 3 children execs and run `./program1` from the terminal, then the system never finishes. When I check the output files, one output is as expected, one output is empty, and one output prints the correct data infinitely many times.

Can anyone can explain what's likely going on!? Or explain what a stackdump file is and how to inspect it, or suggest how I can do to fix this?

Here is a general idea of what my code looks like:

```
//program1.c
#define INPUT1 "in1.txt" 
#definte OUTPUT1 "out1.txt" 
// same for rest of input/output files

char* my_argv[2];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char prog_name[20] = "helper";
    char prog_name2[20] = "simpleWrite";

    my_argv[0] = "helper";
    my_argv[1] = NULL;


    pid_t   pid1, pid2, pid3, pid;
    int     status;

     if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0) {
          printf("Failed to fork process 1\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid1 == 0)
     {
         // redirection here for the child only
        int fd_in = open_file_desc(INPUT1);
        int fd_out = open_file_desc(OUTPUT1);

        dup2(fd_in, 0);
        dup2(fd_out,1);

        close(fd_in); 
        close(fd_out);

        execve(prog_name, my_argv, NULL);
        //alternately, execve(prog_name2, my_argv, NULL);
     }

     if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0) {
          //...
     }
     else if (pid2 == 0) 
     {
        int fd_in2 = open_file_desc(INPUT2);
        int fd_out2 = open_file_desc(OUTPUT2);
        ...// same idea as above
     }

     // likewise for pid3 
     ...

     //back in parent process
     pid = wait(&status);
     printf("\n***Parent detects process %d was terminated ***\n", pid);
     pid = wait(&status);
     printf("\n*** Parent detects process %d was terminated ***\n", pid);
     pid = wait(&status);
     printf("\n*** Parent detects process %d was terminated ***\n", pid);

    // dup2(sav_stdin, 0);
    // dup2(sav_stdout, 1);
    // dup2(sav_stderr, 2);
    exit(0);
}
```

```
//helper.c
enum POLYGON { HEXAGON = 6, HEPTAGON = 7, OCTAGON = 8 };

struct point {
    short *X, *Y;
};

struct polygon
{
    enum POLYGON type;
    struct point points;
};

struct Node {
    struct polygon* poly;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *HEAD = NULL;
struct Node *TAIL = NULL;

int main()
{
    int lastCommand = 0, polygonscreated =0, newPolygonBit;
    //other variables needed for parsing/calculations

    while (!lastCommand)
    {
        scanf("%llx", &input);
        //parsing stuff

        if (newPolygonBit == 1)
        {
            polygonscreated = polygonscreated+1;
            scanf("%llx", &setOfPoints1);
            scanf("%llx", &setOfPoints2);
            struct polygon* polyptr = createPolygon(polyType, setOfPoints1, setOfPoints2);

            func[ADD_POLYGON](polyptr);
        }

        lastCommand = input & 1;
    }

    freeList(HEAD);
    printf("Created %d polygons", polygonscreated);
    return polygonscreated;
}
```

```
//simpleWrite.c
int main()
{
    char c;

    while( read(0, &c, 1) > 0){ 
      write(1, &c,1); 
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a similar code.

My problem was that I expected my child process to execute in a specific order. In this case let's say you want your 3 child to execute as follow:
-Child A
-Child B
-Child C

But the scheduler might execute them in a different order. Let's say A-C-B.

I hope this can help.